# Text writing in c#

Tags: c#

How can i write down the random variable that was used 
for example.

```
string[] fnames = { "Aleisha", "Sadye", "Ethyl");
string[] lname = {"Smith","Johnson","Melody");
Random r = new Random();
int wfname = r.Next(fnames.Length);
int wlname = r.Next(lnames.Length);
```

So if the name "Aleisha" and "Smith" is used how can i write that in the text file.

I already know this code below. But, i need it to use the random one that is picked not another random one. if that makes sense.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\names.txt", wfnames + wlname);
```

Comment: did you tried with (@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\names.txt",  fnames [wfname -1]+ lname[wlname -1] )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string[] fnames = { "Aleisha", "Sadye", "Ethyl" };
string[] lnames = { "Smith", "Johnson", "Melody" };
Random r = new Random();
int wfname = r.Next(fnames.Length);
int wlname = r.Next(lnames.Length);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\names.txt", new[] {
fnames[wfname ],
lnames[wlname  ]});
```

Answer (score 0):

You already generated your random indexes to pick the first name and last name, after that you need to get the corresponding strings in your arrays and output the full name in the file by building an array with a single item (since WriteAllLines expects an array of string, each string corresponding to a line in the final file) :

```
string[] fnames = { "Aleisha", "Sadye", "Ethyl");
string[] lname = {"Smith","Johnson","Melody");
Random r = new Random();
int wfname = r.Next(fnames.Length);
int wlname = r.Next(lnames.Length);

var fullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", fnames[wfname], lname[wlname]);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\names.txt", new [] { fullName });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how you can write down the string that was chosen out of the array then you would simply use `wfname` and `wlname` to grab the strings that were selected. E.G.

`fnames[wfname]` and `lname[wlname]`

Comment: My mistake. Edited out

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a structure like the following, where you'll have lists of these names and use a random int to pick a name out of the index and then remove it immediately after using it heres an example

```
List<string> fNames = new List<string>() {"Aleisha", "Sadye", "Ethyl"};
List<string> lNames = new List<string>() {"Smith", "Johnson", "Melody"};
Random r = new Random();
int wFName = r.Next(0, fNames.Count);
int wLName = r.Next(0, lNames.Count);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\names.txt", fNames[wFName] + lNames[wLName]);
fNames.Remove(wFName);
lNames.Remove(lFName);
```

Try this out and let me know how you go, if you need any further explanation feel free to say so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-:

```
string[] fnames = { "Aleisha", "Sadye", "Ethyl");
string[] lname = {"Smith","Johnson","Melody");
Random r = new Random();
string wfname = r.Next(fnames[0],fnames[2]);
string wlname = r.Next(lnames[0],lnames[2]);

var name = string.Format("{0} {1}", wfname, wlname);
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\names.txt", new [] { name });
```